# When I add shared_preferences dependency in pubspec.yaml my project doesn't run

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-dependencies

when I add Shared_Preferences dependency my project doesn't run

Version : last version 2.2.0

This is the error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android'. Could not resolve all files for configuration ':shared_preferences_android:classpath'. Could not find gradle-7.2.2.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2). Failed to notify project evaluation listener. Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':shared_preferences_android' of
```

**I added `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` in the main function. When I remove the dependency my problem did get solved, but I need this dependency for save token as string**

When I remove the dependency my problem did get solved.

Comment: Sometimes some packages can conflict with other packages and show errors. I fixed myself by exchanging/considering other package versions. 
How about your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: The problem is stated in the error message output: "Could not find gradle-7.2.2.jar" and that problem occurred configuring project ':shared_preferences_android' which means the issue is not with flutter nor with WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); line. What is your gradle config, can you share the build.gradle file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure your gradle version is updated

location => android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
```

location => android/build.gradle

```
dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2' }
```

after that, you can add your dependencies from the terminal

```
flutter clean 

flutter pub add shared_preferences
flutter pub get
```

Comment: It's right I should update Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Check your `pubspec.yaml` file to ensure that you have added the shared_preferences dependency correctly. It should look something like this:

```
dependencies:

  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  shared_preferences: ^2.2.0
```

Run the command `flutter pub get` in your project directory to fetch the dependencies.